# Kill the execution of controller after $this->load->view, Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I am using codeigniter for site and i am calling a function in a controller through a form in my php page the function call is:

Gear.php:

```
foreach ($gearArray as $key => $value) {

                echo '<tr><td><img id="leftimg" src="'.base_url().''.$value["Product_Image_URL"].'"></td>';
                echo '<td>'.$value["Description"].'';
                echo '<form method="post" id="addtocart" action="'.site_url('GearController/addorUpdate').'">';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="desc1" value="'.$value["Name"].'">';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="cost1" value="'.$value["Price"].'">';
                echo '<input type="submit" value="Add To Cart">';
                echo '</form></td>';
            }
            echo '</table>';
            ?>
```

From this the method inside the GearController is called through

> action="'.site_url('GearController/addorUpdate').'"

inside the function which is an add to cart function, i am checking whether the item is already in the cart or not and then updating it,once updated i am trying to redirect to a page using:

GearController.php:

```
  public function addorUpdate(){
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->load->model('CartModel','cart');
            $boolean = FALSE;
            $Description = $this->input->post('desc1');
            $data['cartArray'] = $this->cart->return_cart();
            foreach ($data['cartArray'] as $value) {

                if($Description==$value['Description']){
                    $boolean = TRUE;

                }

            }
            if($boolean==TRUE){
                $this->updateCart($Description);

            }

        }
public function updateCart($Description){
        $updatearray = array(
                'Quantity'=>'Quantity+1',
                'Price' => 'Price * Quantity',
            );
            $this->load->model('CartModel','cart'); 
            $update_order = $this->cart->update_cart($updatearray,$Description);
            $data['cartArray'] = $this->cart->return_cart();
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->view('cart',$data);

    }
```

The problem here is that everything works fine, the page gets redirected but within seconds it displays a blank screen. I tried return, die and exit. None of it helps. It seems like the controller is executing the code under the $this->load->view. I am telling this because i previously had a function under the

> if($boolean==TRUE){
>                     $this->updateCart($Description);
>
> ```
>           }
> ```

That particular code was executed after the redirect. Could someone please help?

Comment: `I tried return, die and exit.`  there is no way PHP will execute code after it hits any of these, your issue is before these.  PHP just doesn't do what it wants it does what you tell it to.

Comment: The logic in your foreach is also flawed, or well could be better, you can `break` after you find the first true for your condition.  And a little tip is when checking constants its preferable to put them on the left side `if(TRUE==$boolean)` this prevents assignment, because you cant assign true to something where you could assign `$boolean`, however in this case I would just `if($boolean)` which is equivalent to what you are checking.  None of these fix your issue, but I thought I would share my wisdom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sound like you might have what is call a `BOM` character at the start of your view file. This character is usually invisible. Make sure that there are not (apparently) black characters at the beginning.

You can also test that `updateCart($Description)` is running by temporarily putting this code as the first line of the function `echo "This is updateCart;` Then comment out all the other code in that function. If you see that text on the screen you know the function runs.

Comment: You can also open it in Notepad++ and then check what encoding it has.  I hate those BOM things `<<<`  I had to develop a Regex to strip them from a clients CSV files, what a pain in the butt.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question but it's bugging me so...

Instead of this mess

```
foreach ($data['cartArray'] as $value) {

    if($Description==$value['Description']){
        $boolean = TRUE;
    }

}
if($boolean==TRUE){
    $this->updateCart($Description);
}
```

You could simply do this

```
if(in_array( $Description, array_column($data['cartArray'],'Description'))){
   $this->updateCart($Description);
}
```

You can test it with this code (mockup)

```
$Description = 'foo';

$data = ['cartArray' => [
        ['Description' => 'foo'],
        ['Description' => 'bar'],
    ]
];

if(in_array( $Description, array_column($data['cartArray'],'Description'))){
   echo "found";
}
```

Outputs

```
 found
```

Test it here

https://3v4l.org/W5oB5

I think `in_array` is pretty self evident but here is [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) which is highly useful and often overlooked.